# Prevent navigation in iframe with third party content from affecting top level history

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page in which I am loading third party content into an iframe. The intention is to allow third party functionality within my page. I have no control over the third party content as it is coming from a different domain and I want to allow that third party content to do anything it needs. The only limitation is that it must stay within the iframe.

I want to allow the third party content to navigate to other pages within the iframe, but I do not want such action to affect the top level browser history. Take this scenario for example:

1. User visits page `A` on my site.
2. User clicks a link on page `A` that takes them to page `B` on my site.
3. On page `B`, there is an iframe which loads third party content, which displays page third party page `X` in the iframe.
4. User clicks on a link in the iframe's page `X` that redirects the iframe to page `Y`.
5. User clicks the browser's back button.

Currently, the iframe navigates back to page `X` when the user clicks the back button. I want the back button in this case to navigate the top level page back to page `A` on my site, essentially ignoring any number of page navigations within the iframe.

Is there a way to prevent page navigations inside an iframe from affecting the top level page history in the case where I do not have control nor access (due to XSS restrictions) to the iframe content?

Note: there are other posts on SO that ask the similar questions, but the difference here is that those questions have control over the iframe content. I do not have control over the iframe content in this scenario.

Comment: have you tried any code ?

Comment: Yes. Tried window.history, listening for popstate, and attaching beforeunload/unload/load listeners to the iframe window. Nothing fires. The only thing I found was setting an interval that watches window.history.length. That polling can detect when the history length changes, but that doesn't provide any ability to prevent the top level history from changing.